# Why reorder not working after button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have menu options (which have text and a button) I have to open menu option on button click .
Could you please tell me why rerender not working when I click on button

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-albattani-qvtec

```
const HeaderFilter = ({ menu }) => {
  const { type, open } = menu;
  const showFilters = () => {
    switch (type) {
      case "text":
        break;
      case "dropdown":
        const cls = open ? "open" : "";
        return (
          <div className={`primary-filter ${cls}`}>
            <p>
              <button
                className={`icon-chevron-left ${cls}`}
                onClick={() => {
                  menu.open = !open;
                }}
              >
                open
              </button>
            </p>
            <ul className="primary-filter--menu">
              {menu.options.map(i => (
                <li>
                  <Checkbox
                    value={i}
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
                  />
                  {i}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
  };

  return <>{showFilters()}</>;
};

export default HeaderFilter;
```

Comment: have you consider using `state`? DOM re-renders when you update state. (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

const HeaderFilter = ({ menu }) => {
  const { type } = menu;
  const [open, setopen] = useState(menu.open);

  const showFilters = () => {
    switch (type) {
      case "text":
        break;
      case "dropdown":
        const cls = open ? "open" : "";
        return (
          <div className={`primary-filter ${cls}`}>
            <p>
              <button
                className={`icon-chevron-left ${cls}`}
                onClick={() => setopen(!open)}
              >
                open
              </button>
            </p>
            <ul className="primary-filter--menu">
              {menu.options.map(i => (
                <li>
                  <Checkbox
                    value={i}
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
                  />
                  {i}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
  };

  return <>{showFilters()}</>;
};

export default HeaderFilter;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bird-h8wuv

Answer (score 1):

Because that's not how you handle component state in React. You can read up on component state in the [state documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). Unless React is aware of your state, it won't re-render anything when your state changes.

To have `menu.open` be state, you need to use a class component or the `useState` hook.

In your case, you're getting `menu.open` from the parent (as a prop), so you'd probably want to have the update occur in the parent as well (so that when the parent re-renders, your component state isn't lost). See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up).

**If** you were handling it as state in your component (which you probably shouldn't; or at least, not *only* in your component), then:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(menu.open);
```

...and then in the button click handler:

```
setOpen(!open);
```

Answer (score 0):

because menu its not a setstate function

```
const [open,setopen] = useState(menu.open)


 onClick={()=>setopen(!open)}
```

or you need to pass function from parent component that will change your state,never change ur state with '=' you need to do it with function setstate so react will update and rerender

Answer (score 0):

Your parent file (App.js) has the menu data and passes it along to the child file (Header.js). What is sent, however, is not the original menu data, but a copy of it.

Your child file (Header.js) tries to change its value, but the original is not changed. The way React works is to continuously re-render every time there is a likely change in what would be displayed. So your change to the *copy* of the 'open' property is lost, because a new copy is made and sent down.

What you need to do is allow the parent's copy to be modified. Generally you would do this by tracking the modifiable data in state, not as a const.

In the fork I made of your code, I kept the const but added id's to each menu item so that they can be targetted. Then I added state (useState hook) to create state based off of your const, with ability for it to be modified.

```
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(TASK_LIST_HEADER);
  const toggleMenu = id => {
    const newMenuState = menu.map(menuItem => {
      if (menuItem.id === id) {
        menuItem.menu.open = !menuItem.menu.open;
      }
      return menuItem;
    });
    setMenu(newMenuState);
  };
```

The `toggleMenu` function takes as a parameter an id, i.e. which menu item do we want to update? Then it uses the `setMenu` part of the state hook to update the menu in state with the newly opened (or closed) menu item.

The toggleMenu function is then passed down to the child (Header) so that it can be called from there.

Working fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-lichterman-rgdfy